# The getter 'auth' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: auth

Tags: flutter

I have this error in my Flutter app:

> **The getter 'auth' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: auth**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smartbin/services/provider.dart';
import 'package:auro_avatar/auro_avatar.dart';

class Profile extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Profile'),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green[800]),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[400],
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            InitialNameAvatar(
              "",
              circleAvatar: true,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
```

// Raised button for editing

```
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text('Edit'),
                  new Icon(Icons.edit),
                ],
              ),
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
            ),
```

// future builder for importing data from firebase

```
            FutureBuilder(
              future: Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID(),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
                  {
                    return Text("${snapshot.hasData}");
                  }
              },
            ),
```

// custom widget to make icon text

```
            buildProfile(
              icon: Icons.person,
              text: 'Name:',
              subtext: '',
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30),
            buildProfile(
              icon: Icons.email,
              text: "Email:",
              subtext: '',
            )
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

//custom Widgets

```
class buildProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  IconData icon;
  String text;
  String subtext;
  buildProfile({this.text, this.icon, this.subtext});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(icon),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        Text(text,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontFamily: 'Solway',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            )),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        Text(subtext,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontFamily: 'Solway',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The error comes from future builder saying that auth was called on null. I hope you guys can help me. Thank you.

**Edit**
The provider code is here.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:smartbin/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Provider extends InheritedWidget {
  final AuthService auth;

  Provider({Key key, Widget child, this.auth}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }

  static Provider of(BuildContext context) =>
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Provider>());
}
```

Comment: The first thing that I see wrong is `Provider.of(context)`... that is not enough for flutter to know what type you're trying to resolve. try `Provider.of<Auth>(context)`... I would like to see how you setup provider though.

Comment: There's no option of Auth Provider. It gives me this error:- the name 'AuthProvider' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument. I tried with <EmailAuthProvider> but still the same error:- The getter 'auth' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: auth.  I added provider plugin but don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from your `FutureBuilder` you called `.auth` with no Provider.
You did this

```dart
Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID()
```

which means you did not specify any `Provider`. You should access your provider like this

```dart
Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context).auth.getCurrentUID() //replace AuthProvider with your provider's name
```

Comment: There's no option of Auth Provider.It gives me this errorThe name 'AuthProvider' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument. I tried with <EmailAuthProvider> but still same error The getter 'auth' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: auth.

Comment: I just saw your provider code, I dont think that how you should create a provider

Comment: How should I do it then? please help

Comment: You should add the provider plugin and follow the docs on how to set it up not creating your own `Provider` class

Comment: I added Provider plugin from pub.dev but don't know how to use it . Help

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the provider

```
Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context).auth.getCurrentUID()
```

Comment: There's no option of Auth Provider.It gives me this error:-The name 'AuthProvider' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument. I tried with <EmailAuthProvider> but still same error. The getter 'auth' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: auth